# Magento 2 : Add product to cart as per customer with custom price programmatically

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote

I need to add product to cart as per customer vise with custom price.

I'm trying by below code. But, it returns error

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::setCustomer() must implement interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface, instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor given, called in /media/vendor/ssd_drive/mage2/abcd/app/code/vendor/module/Controller/Index/test.php on line 133 and defined in /media/vendor/ssd_drive/mage2/abcd/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:974

How to solve it ?

Controller code :

```
protected $_customer;
protected $quote;
protected $_customerSession;
protected $cart;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->quote = $quote;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------

$customerid = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
$customerData = $this->_customer->load($customerid);
$quote_data = $this->quote->loadByCustomer($customerData);
if (!$quote_data->getId()) {
    $quote_data->setCustomer($customerData); //error line here
    $quote_data->setIsActive(1);
    $quote_data->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
}
$quote_data->addProduct($_products, $params);
$quote_data->collectTotals()->save();

$cart = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$subtotal = 0;
if ($cart) {
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $productID) {
            $subprice = $this->priceCurrency->currency($customprice, false, false);
            $finalprice = round($subprice, 2);
            $item->setCustomPrice($finalprice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalprice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $item->save();
        }
        $subtotal += $item->getCustomPrice();
    }
    $quote_data->setSubtotal($subtotal);
    $quote_data->setGrandTotal($subtotal);
    $quote_data->save();
}
```

**Note : I do this inside controller not using observer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` try `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` with `getById()` and then pass `$customerData` in  `$quote_data->setCustomer($customerData);`

Comment: You most welcome

Comment: one more thing : When I go to checkout/shipping page at first time, second product price not getting update in order summary block.  It's just generate issue only first time.

Comment: @Rakesh Varma, this code is not working inside model.i am getting one error while execution i.e. "We found an invalid request for adding product to quote."